# Python Logging: Not showing on terminal

Tags: python

logging3.py

```
import sys
import logging
import first
import Logger

root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(Logger.get_streamhandler())
root.warning('we did something in info')

hi = first.Foo()
hi.baz()
```

first.py

```
import logging

import Logger

first_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
first_logger.parent = False
first_logger.addHandler(Logger.get_streamhandler())
first_logger.info('in first')


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'making sure we are in first.Foo' 
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
        self.logger.addHandler(Logger.get_streamhandler())
        self.logger.info('created Foo obj')
    def baz(self):
        self.logger.info('i dont know what baz is')
```

Logger.py

```
  1 import logging
  2 import sys
  3
  4
  5 '''
  6     NOTSET means inherit the log level from the parent logger
  7 '''
  8
  9 LEVELS = {  'debug'   : logging.DEBUG,
 10             'info'    : logging.INFO,
 11             'warning' : logging.WARNING,
 12             'error'   : logging.ERROR,
 13             'critical': logging.CRITICAL,
 14          }
 15
 16 def getLevel(lvl):
 17     return LEVELS.get(lvl) or logging.DEBUG
 18
 19 def get_streamhandler(lvl=None):
 20     sh =  logging.StreamHandler()
 21     fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
 22     sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
 23     sh.setLevel(getLevel(lvl))
 24     return sh
```

~

OUTPUT:
python logging3.py

```
2013-10-21 14:18:09,687 - first - INFO - in first  
2013-10-21 14:18:09,687 - root - WARNING - we did something in info  
making sure we are in first.Foo
```

Where is logging info for Foo object?       <---------------

Also, can someone confirm that logging tree for the above is

root
----first
---------foo

or is it
root
----root.first
--------------root.first.foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's intentional. The logger has a loglevel (separate for console and file); you can set them with

```
foo.setConsoleLevel(logging.ERROR)
foo.setFileLevel(logging.INFO)
```

etc. If you change your loglevel to logging.INFO (which is 0x14 on my python 2.6 session) or below, then you will see the log messages.

Logging messages that are below the current loglevel are suppressed; only messages at or above the current level are passed through. This means that info messages can go to the file, but not to the screen, or that you can change the level to debug to get additional output while debugging, etc.